# Img bullet points appear above paragraph React.js

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I am having issues with my bullet point alignment in my react project for class, ever since i used the image to replace my bullet points it appears above the paragraph its meant to be next to.

here is my HTML:

```
  <ul className="list">
<li className="star">
  <div className="key">
    <p className="keyTitle">THINKING</p>
    <p className="keyPara">
      In particular the programme focused on prblem solving, design thinking
      and computational thinking.
    </p>
  </div>
</li>
```

and here is my CS:

```
body{
  background-color: #d3d3d3;
  height: 634px;
}

.key{
  margin-top: 1rem;
}
ul{
  list-style-type: none;
}

li:before{
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  background-size: 40px;
  background-image: url("LogoListImage.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  margin-right: 5px;
}

.keyTitle{
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: Nunito;
  margin-bottom: 1px;
  margin-left: 0px;
  margin-right: 0px;
  margin-top: 0px;
}
.keyPara{
  font-family: OpenSans;
  margin: 0px;
}

.title{
  font-family: Nunito;
}

.container{
  width: 100%;
}
```

I think its a simple fix but I just cant figure it out so if anyone could help me out then that would be absolutely amazing

Comment: What if you `display: inline;` the `li:before` selector?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use the before attribute you need to give the values absolute and top, left.

add to ul tag:

```
     position: relative
```

add to li tag:

```
     top: 0; left:0; content:"*" (content is example)
```

Your code for example:

```
 ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  position: relative;
}

li:before {
  content: "*";
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  background-size: 40px;
  background-image: url("LogoListImage.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  margin-right: 5px;
}
```

Comment: Omg thankyou so much I've been stressing out about this problem for so long.